# Cannot make a join between table Working on read but not on insert

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I'm trying to join three tables with hibernate. 
When I do read method it works but when I save I have a Null pointer issue
The third table Id is auto_increment.

[image: The diagram]

Thanks for help !

This is the join table (THIRD and ONE table ID should not be null )

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "SECOND_TABLE")
public class SecondTableEntity
    implements Serializable {

 @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FIRST_TABLE_KEY")
    private FirstTable firstTable;

    @Id
    @MapsId("id")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "THIRD_TABLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "THIRD_TABLE_ID")
    private ThirdTable thirdTable;

    @Column(name = "SECOND_TABLE_VALUE")
    private String secondTable;

}
```

In this table the ID is auto_increment

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "THIRD_TABLE")
public class ThirdTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "THIRD_TABLE_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "THIRD_TABLE_NAME")
    private String thirdTableName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SECOND_TABLE_ID")
    private List<SecondTable> secondTable = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here the Id is auto increment too

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "FIRST_TABLE")
public class FirstTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "FIRST_TABLE_ID")
    private Integer firstTable;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_TABLE_NAME")
    private String firstTableName;
```

The issue is that hibernate should save one table and third table before save SECOND_TABLE

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Your `@Table` annotation specifies that the name is `FIRST_TABLE` and your schema that it should be `ONE_TABLE`, or is that just a typo when anonymising for stackoverflow? Also what code is causing the null pointer?

Comment: Ooops sorry you right it's just a typo .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I found the Issue.

I added a Embedded key in SECOND_TABLE instead of having @Id on the both object